# Better approach to pass activity context to getLastLocation inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, location

> LocationFragment.java

```
LocationActivity activity;

onCreateView(){
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
        .addOnSuccessListener(activity, new OnSuccessListener<Location>(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if(location != null){
                    // update UI here ..
                }
            }
         }
    );
}

onAttach(){
    activity = (LocationActivity) context;
}
```

Is this the correct approach for passing activity to Google Location API or not, If so why? Please explain this with proper reason like memory leak, etc, if any?

Answer (score -1):

Use `getActivity()` to get Activity context inside Fragment.

```
addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>(){
    .....
}
```